# Method ... should return array<a|b|c|d...,mixed> but returns array('key1'=>SomeObject|null,'key2'=>SomeObject2|null)

Tags: php, phpstan

I am new to PHPStan and I encountered an issue that I can't understand.

So I have a function, that supposed to return an array that looks like this: `array<a|b|c|d..., mixed>` (a,b,c,d are all class constants), but in the function, the array looks something like this:

```
/**
 * @return array<SomeConstants::*, mixed>
 */
function doSomething(){

return [
'key1'=>'value1'
'key2'=>'value2'
...
];

}
```

I get the following error:

`Method doSomething() should return array<a|b|c|d...,mixed> but returns array('key1'=>SomeObject|null,'key2'=>SomeObject2|null)`

How can I make PHPStan "believe" that this array "looks like" the array that is defined in the @return doc tag?

### What have I tried?

- `/**@var array<SomeConstants::*> $array**/`
- `/**@phpstan-var array<SomeConstants::*> $array**/`

Both works fine, but according to my code reviewer, we just force PHPStan believe that keys that are not present in the array are present, so it's a "dirty" solution...

Comment: Are you using the latesr PHPStan version 0.12.99? Can you reproduce this problem on phpstan.org?